# Jenkins JLNP agent not responding

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

I am trying to use jenkins and kubernetesplugin. I deployed a kubernetes cluster in AWS using kubeadm and I installed jenkins on a EC2 VM.

I am trying to initiate the deployment of pods in the kubernetes clusters using pipelines in jenkins.

However I keep getting an agent time  out:

```
Waiting for agent to connect (30/100): mypod-67j9m-nqz0g
Feb 05, 2020 6:30:39 PM INFO org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesLauncher launch
Container is terminated mypod-67j9m-nqz0g [jnlp]: ContainerStateTerminated(containerID=docker://8021b8da7c087efd6c84085032c56b5523ca7492332e441fa302a561b93b9829, exitCode=255, finishedAt=2020-02-05T18:30:38Z, message=null, reason=Error, signal=null, startedAt=2020-02-05T18:30:07Z, additionalProperties={})
Feb 05, 2020 6:30:39 PM SEVERE org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesLauncher logLastLines
Error in provisioning; agent=KubernetesSlave name: mypod-67j9m-nqz0g, template=PodTemplate{, name='mypod-67j9m', label='mypod', nodeUsageMode=EXCLUSIVE, workspaceVolume=EmptyDirWorkspaceVolume [memory=false], containers=[ContainerTemplate{name='golang', image='golang:1.8.0', command='cat', ttyEnabled=true}], annotations=[org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.PodAnnotation@aab9c821]}. Container jnlp exited with error 255. Logs: Feb 05, 2020 6:30:08 PM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.WorkDirManager setupLogging
INFO: Both error and output logs will be printed to /home/jenkins/agent/remoting
Feb 05, 2020 6:30:08 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Locating server among [http://ec2-18-140-64-62.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/]
Feb 05, 2020 6:30:38 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener error
SEVERE: Failed to connect to http://xxxxx.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/tcpSlaveAgentListener/: connect timed out
```

My pod is running but there is no response from the slave pod and the message states that

`JNLP agent port is disabled and agents cannot connect this way`

this is my current set up

```
podTemplate(cloud: 'kubernetes', label: 'mypod',containers: [
    containerTemplate(name: 'golang', image: 'golang:1.8.0', ttyEnabled: true, command: 'cat')
  ]) {

    node('mypod') {

        stage('Get a Golang project') {
            git url: 'https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform.git'
            container('golang') {
                stage('Build a Go project') {
                    sh 'echo hello world'
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The slave connects back to Jenkins via JNLP on JNLP port (TCP port for incoming agents). If you will go to Manage > Configure Global Security; you would be able to see that; select Fixed port and specify a value say 50000.

Comment: HI Pankaj, I dont see the  JNLP option, there is only TCP port for inbound agents under agents section

Comment: Yeah, that's the one (TCP port for inbound agents) as mentioned in brackets in the comment above :)